# rails devise: user and account model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am trying to customize the sign up page by adding an additional field, name.

This is done by adding a Profile model to my app.

```
    class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_attributes

  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

I overrode the registration model:

```
    # app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
    profile = @user.build_profile

  end

  def create
    super   

  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

And my new sign up page:

```
    <h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><% f.fields_for :profile do |builder| %>
    <p><%= builder.label :name %></p>
    <p><%= builder.text_field :name %></p>
  <% end %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "links" %>
```

However, I am not sure if everything else works, but the registration page still looks the same. That is, it doesn't show the name input field. How do I fix this?

What am I missing?

Comment: 1.make sure your profile instance is exist,you can put some code like `<%= f.object.profile.inspect%>` before call `f.fields_for` 2.check whether your new sign_up template is used, if you generate scoped devise views, then make sure you have this line `config.scoped_views = true` on devise.rb of initializers dir

Comment: theres a profile, but its attributes are are nil...including id, is that the problem?

Comment: try to change `attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_attributes` to `attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :profile_attributes, :profile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you did not generate the views. Did you run the following?

```
rails generate devise:views
```

More information on changing views can be found in "Configuring views" on the devise wiki:

```
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
```

Thanks,

Tabrez